# Android : Add Button to Web View from XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I am developing an android application and I need to display HTML page.

I managed to do this using the web view as below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </WebView>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/disease_consultation_button"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/buttonWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            style="@style/buttonStyle"
            android:text="@string/continue_button" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and from java code

```
WebView webView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.disease_web_view_activity);

       webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
       webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

       String customHtml = "<html><body><h1>Hello, WebView</h1></body></html>";
       webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");

    }
```

the button doesn't appear in the view and I don't know why ?

can anyone help me please ?

the view looks like this

[image: The view appearing]

EDIT : This is what I did and solved the problem =)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >    

     <TextView android:id="@+id/disease_consultation_titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/activityTitle" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/disease_consultation_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="550dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            style="@style/buttonStyle"
            android:text="@string/request_new_consultation" />

    <WebView 
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp" >

    </WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to place first button (or another layout to contain more than one items) and then add you WebView e.g.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

It won't appear. :)

A `WebView` is like a browser, it renders the content of a HTML page.
So if you need to display a button in your `WebView`, you should create a HTML page with that button and give the url to `WebView` do display it.

Include a HTML button in your code, if you would like to display one:

```
String customHtml = "<html><body><h1>Hello, WebView</h1>
                         <button type="button">Click Me!</button> 
                     </body></html>";
```

Comment: That's what i am trying to do now. how do I add action listener to that button ? and what if i want to give it an ID to be able to control this button using android java code ?

Comment: You can't add action listener to a HTML button. For what you want to achieve you need to have some basic knowledge about pure HTML.

Comment: I know I can't add action listener to a button in HTML that's why I was trying to add the button in the XML file .

thank you for you help :) ...I think what I want to do can't be done so I will find a work around.

Answer (score 0):

The default orientation of a `LinearLayout` is horizontal. Since your WebView matches the width of the parent element (which is `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`), the WebView will use all width available.

To solve your problem, make the orientation of the `LinearLayout` vertical by setting `android:orientation="vertical"`.
With this, elements in the layout will appear bellow each other, instead of side-by-side.

You can read more on this subject at the [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html).

EDIT: code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </WebView> 

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/disease_consultation_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/buttonWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:text="@string/continue_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```